# a href if condition regarding to which mailing list the user belongs

Tags: html, google-sheets

is there a possibility to make an IF condition inside a href, that would pick different cell regarding the mailing list, to which the user belongs.

example:
 a href="{{URL}}" target="_bottom"

where the URL is taken from a cell 'URL', but I would like to make an IF condition:
if the user belongs to mailing list blabla@blabla then use another cell as URL

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not possible with plain HTML, you need to use JavaScript for that

Comment: I am working in Google Sheet, so this means I need to use Google Script. Can you tell me under which keywords should I look to find information online? I honestly have no much experience with this. And other thing is, the sheet is working with 'awesome table' add-on

Comment: Ok, I wrote sth like this: `function onOpen() {

 var currentmail= Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var source = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
 var values = source.getRange(3,7,source.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var ALvalues = source.getRange(3,12,source.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 
{
 if (currentmail= "blabla@blabla.com") {
 
ss.getSheetByName("Responses").getRange(3,13,values.length,1).setValues(values)
 
 }
 else{
 
ss.getSheetByName("Responses").getRange(3,13,values.length,1).setValues(ALvalues)
 
 }
}
}`

Comment: Does it make any sense?

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not in a comment :)